# Why I fetched data after component loading?

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular5, angular-httpclient

I have some problem with http request on Angular2 (version 5).
I have a service `data-service.service.ts` and a component  `real-time-value.component.ts`.

I want to fetch data from a fake json, add to array and display on  `real-time-value.component.ts`. 
My problem is that I retrive my `system`  after my component was loading. 
I attached the code of files and a image of console report.
I need to resolve this problem because I have several components and I have to use the same data. On  `real-time-value.component.ts` I have to show only the name, but with routing I have to show other details of My

I have two question:
How can I load correctly my data on `real-time-value.component.ts`?

How Console print array twice?

```
#### real-time-value.component.ts

import {Injectable, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {SystemModel} from './system.model';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
@Injectable()
export class DataServiceService implements OnInit{

  private systemUrl = 'http://my-json-server.typicode.com/nicscap/fake_json/ImpiantiProva';  // URL to web api

  private systems: SystemModel[] = [];

  getSystems_1() {
    this.fetchSystem();
    return this.systems;
  }

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('start ngOnInit');
  }
  fetchSystem() {
    this.http.get<SystemModel[]>(this.systemUrl)
      .subscribe(
        data=> {
          console.log('I\'m Inside  subscribe');
          this.systems = data;
          console.log(data);
        },
        (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          if (err.error instanceof Error) {
                       console.log('An error occurred:', err.error.message);
          } else {

            console.log(`Backend returned code ${err.status}, body was: ${err.error}`);
          }
        }
      );
  }      
}
```

```
   ###data-service.service.ts

    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

    import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
    import { Location } from '@angular/common';
    import {DataServiceService} from '../shared/data-service.service';


    @Component({
      selector: 'app-real-time-value',
      templateUrl: './real-time-value.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./real-time-value.component.css']
})


export class RealTimeValueComponent implements OnInit {
  public systems = [];

  constructor(private _dataService: DataServiceService,
              private route: ActivatedRoute,
              ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('i\'M ON ngOnInit');
    this.system= this._dataService.getSystems_1();
    console.log('console.log BEFORE data retrive from data-service.service.ts');
    console.log(this.systems);
    console.log('console.log AFTER data retrive from data-service.service.ts');
  }
}
```

[image: Console report]

thanks

Comment: Are `fetchImpianti()` and `this.impianti`  typos in your code?  Should they be `fetchSystem()` and `this.systems` respectively?

Comment: Hi, yes sorry I change name of function from italian to english for who read! FetchImpianti() = fetchSystem() and this.impianti = this.systems

Comment: I edit the question with right name!

Comment: `OnInit()` is only part of component's lifecycle. The `ngOnInit()` method you have inside your service will never be called.

Comment: Have a look at https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks to have a better understanding on component lifecycle hooks

Comment: Have a look at https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-guard if you want to fetch data before a component is loaded

Comment: You also really need to know how `Observable` works. Have a look at http://reactivex.io/rxjs/